# Automating Flash App

Tags: java, flash, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is there a way to automate with webdriver java, Flash applications? I found a couple of post but nothing concrete. If it's posible can some point me out were to look or were to download a proyect.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can use [UiPath](http://www.uipath.com) in order to automate flash (and also web and desktop) applications.

Here's a [flash automation example](http://pages.uipath.com/examples/flash-automation). You can use it from code (SDK) or create an workflow (visual) automation directly from UiPath Studio.

Comment: Thanks for your reply seems to fit what we need